# ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource vs ResourceBundleMessageSource - boundle not found

Tags: spring, tomcat, bundle

When I put WAR file with Spring application on Tomcat server, if I use `ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource` everything works fine.

```java
@Bean
AbstractMessageSource messageSource()
{
   ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource bundle 
      = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();

   bundle.setBasename("/WEB-INF/classes/messages");
   return bundle;
}
```

But if I change message source implementation to `ResourceBundleMessageSource`:

```java
@Bean
AbstractMessageSource messageSource()
{
   ResourceBundleMessageSource bundle 
      = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();

   bundle.setBasename("/WEB-INF/classes/messages");
   return bundle;
}
```

I got following error:
`org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource.getResourceBundle ResourceBundle [/WEB-INF/classes/messages] not found for MessageSource: Can't find bundle for base name /WEB-INF/classes/messages, locale pl_PL`

What makes a difference?

Comment: The `ResourceBundleMessageSource` can only load from the classpath because it uses a `ResourceBundle` which is bound to the classpath for loading.

Comment: Ok, but isn't `/WEB-INF/classes/` in classpath?

Comment: No. 'WEB-INF/classes` **is** the classpath. So the basename should be `messages` for the `ResourceBundleMessageSource` else it will look for `/WEB-INF/classes/messages.properties` in `/WEB-INF/classes`. So effectively trying to load `/WEB-INF/classes/WEB-INF/classes/messages.properties`.